# how to write query for 3 where_in() in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a query which run properly but i don't how to write in codeigniter

Here is my query

```
SELECT id,contact,firstname,email 
FROM `user` 
WHERE `id` IN(SELECT id 
              FROM `hr` 
              WHERE `hr_id` IN(SELECT hr_id 
                               FROM `admin_hr` 
                               where id_admin_hr = 8)
              ) AND `id_category` =1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add sub-query part in `where()` method, try this

```
$this->db->select("id,contact,firstname,email")
        ->where("id IN(SELECT id FROM `hr` WHERE `hr_id` IN(SELECT hr_id FROM `admin_hr` where id_admin_hr = 8))")
        ->where("id_category", 1)
        ->get("user")
```